# In Linux how would you see exactly what another process is doing if that process does not have logs?

Tags: linux, monitoring, processes

In Linux how would you see exactly what another process is doing if that process does not have logs?

Comment: `strace` and `ltrace` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
lsof -p process_id
netstat | grep process_id
```

are starting points then you can use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and

```
strace -o logfile program
```